# .NET WinForms grid with multiple scrollbars?

Tags: winforms, grid, scrollbars

Is there a .NET WinForms grid that supports multiple scrollbars, by dividing the grid up into N parts, horizontal-wise, and having a scrollbar for each part?

Example:

```
|---- Part 1 ---|---- Part 2 ---|---- Part 3 ---|
| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 1 | Col 2 |
|<****=========>|<****=========>|<****=========>|
```

Each of those parts have more columns, 3-6 for instance.

So does anyone know of such a grid? Without having to drop 3 grids on the form and using event handling to synchronize vertical scrolling and row height changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [ComponentOne's TrueDBGrid](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/TrueDBGridWinForms/).  Their grid supports horizontal and vertical splits to do exactly what you intend.  I believe the [10Tec's iGrid.NET](http://www.10tec.com/home/Products/dotNET/iGrid.NET/index.aspx) has similar support.